# Is assembly language dangerous?

Tags: assembly

Say I write a program in assembler, and I accidentally use some wrong opcode or introduce a bug of some sort.

Would it be possible, since assembly is such a low-level language, that I could accidentally do something destructive?

Or does the operating system (any or all) keep a good level of resource management, sandboxing, etc. that would mitigate this?

Comment: What do you mean "Destructive" and "dangerous?"

Comment: @Incognito The dictionary definition, "prone to harm".

Comment: @Jarrod [Mankind](http://amzn.com/B003L1ZXCU).

Comment: Does your program control any nuclear devices? Air traffic? Wall street trading?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, if you write incorrect code, then bad things can happen.  This is true in many languages, even high-level ones (consider `System.delete("*.*")` in a hypothetical high-level language).  But in assembler, it's very easy to make mistakes that are difficult to spot.

Answer (score 4):

It's no different than running a C program that might have a bug in it - after all, even your high-level programs eventually end up running machine instructions.  When you program in assembly, you're just starting off a bit closer to that end result.  Unless you're somehow running your code outside the protections the OS provides, you should have no particular problems.

Answer (score 3):

That depends on what you mean by "dangerous".

A developer can make a mistake in any language - low or high level - that can result in undesired behavior. Whether or not the undesired behavior is dangerous depends upon the application.  For example, I work primarily in embedded systems for life-critical medical applications. In my work, a coding error could conceivably harm a patient.  Likewise, another bug could harm the device (for example: consider a timing bug in an LCD screen refresh controller or a logic bug in a power-supply activation or deactivation sequence.)

When working in assembly, the developer assumes almost all responsibility for the code that will be executed. When working in a higher-level language, the compiler takes on some of that burden.  As a result, mistakes can be easily made when a developer resorts to writing "bare-metal" code.  To compensate, a software development program should have good processes in place (good documentation, coding standards, design reviews, code reviews, etc.) to help minimize mistakes.